# How to get HTML(tables) from email body using GMail API in Java

Tags: java, selenium, gmail-api

I have to read some confirmation emails which are developed by tables in HTML.

I'm using GMail API and Java programming language for it.

I'm doing automatization of the registration process so I have to get the link to the confirmation email and click on that confirm button by Selenium test.

In response I'm getting emails with only text, for eg if I send to my mail some random text, I can get that text in response, however, for table kinds of emails I'm getting messages that the body is null.

This is the HTML code of that email.

Image of the email: [Image of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbBR3.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta content="light only" name="color-scheme" />
<meta name="”x-apple-disable-message-reformatting”" />
<style></style>
</head>
<body class="full-width" data-gr-ext-installed="" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.997.0" style="max-width: 600px;width: 100%;background: #333333; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="full-width" style="width: 100%;padding: 1em 0;"><!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--><!--[if mso | IE]>
<table class="full-width" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width: 100%;">
<tr style="    width: 100%;">
<td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->
<div class="full-width" style="    width: 100%;margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;background:#333333;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#1b2940;">
<tbody class="full-width">
<tr class="full-width">
<td class="full-width" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;"><!--[if mso | IE]>
<table class="full-width" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="full-width">
<td class="full-width" style="vertical-align:middle;width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<div aria-labelledby="mj-column-per-100" class="full-width" style="vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="100%">
<tbody class="full-width">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
<tbody><!--                                                                                
<tr>--><!--                                                                                    <td style="width:600px;">--><!--                                                                                        <a href="https://www.24bettle.com/?utm_source=system-email&amp;utm_medium=Image"--><!--                                                                                           target="_blank" >--><!--                                                                                            <img alt="24Bettle Logo"--><!--                                                                                                 src="http://24bettle.com/images/email_images/button-gradient-pic.png"--><!--                                                                                                 style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; clear: both; border: 0px; max-width: 640px; width: 600px; height: 122px; "--><!--                                                                                                 title=""/>--><!--                                                                                        </a>--><!--                                                                                    </td>--><!--                                                                                </tr>-->
<tr>
<td style="width:650px"><img class="first-banner" src="https://24bettle.com/images/banners/24header-image-2.png" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; clear: both; border: 0px; max-width: 600px; width: 100%;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--><!--[if mso | IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->

<div class="full-width" style="    width: 100%;margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;background:#fff;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width" style="padding: 2em 2em;vertical-align:middle;" width="100%">
<tbody class="full-width">
<tr>
<td align="left" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
<div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:20px;">
<p style="font-size: 20px; margin: 0px 0px 15px; color: rgb(76, 76, 76); text-align: center;">Hello {username},</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="full-width">
<td align="left" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
<div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 13px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); vertical-align: middle;" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="word-break: break-word; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<div style="cursor: auto; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); vertical-align: middle;" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="word-break: break-word; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<div style="cursor: auto; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">
<p><span style="font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#333333;">Hit the link to confirm your shiny, new account and enter <strong>24Bettle </strong>- a new dimension of awesome!</span></span></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr><!--                                            style="border: 3px solid #4A8FFF;box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(85,108,108,1);display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;color:white;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:22px;text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #000000;line-height: 20px;font-weight:900;margin:0px; padding:22px 23px; background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, RGB(118, 191, 254) 44%, #1A3380 97%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; no-repeat:padding-box;border-radius: 35px"-->
<td align="center" bgcolor="" style="border-radius:6px;color:white;cursor:auto;background: url(http://24bettle.com/images/email_images/button-gradient-pic.png);background-size: 100% 100%;" valign="middle"><a href="{register_confirmation_url}" id="button" style="background-color: #4587F1;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(85,108,108,0.4);display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:22px;line-height: 20px;font-weight:700;margin:0px;    padding: 22px 35px;border-radius: 35px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; " target="_blank">CONFIRM!</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
<div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:14px;">
<div style="text-align: -webkit-center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: auto; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="full-width" style="margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#333333;">
<tbody class="full-width">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
<div aria-labelledby="mj-column-per-100" class="mj-column-per-100" style="background-color: #333333;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:center;width:100%;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="100%">
<tbody style="background: #141E30; ">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding: 10px 0 0 0;background-color: #333333">
<div style="cursor:auto;color:#CCCCCC;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;line-height:22px;">
<p style="padding: 0 1em;font-family: 'Segoe UI',sans-serif;font-size: 14px; margin: 0; color: #CCCCCC;text-align: -webkit-center;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--><!--[if mso | IE]>
<table class="full-width" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->

<div class="full-width" style="margin:0 auto;max-width:600px;background:#fff;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="full-width" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#fff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;"><!--[if mso | IE]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;width:300px;">
<![endif]--><!--[if mso | IE]>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;width:300px;">
<![endif]--><!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]--></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Users;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Users.Messages;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Users.Messages.Get;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
* Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
* If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
*/

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);

private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

/**
* Creates an authorized Credential object.
* @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
* @return An authorized Credential object.
* @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
*/

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

// Load client secrets.

InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

if (in == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
}

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))

.setAccessType("offline")
.build();

LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, 

// Build a new authorized API client service.

final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
.setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)

.build();

// Print the labels in the user's account.

String user = "me";

ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();

if (labels.isEmpty()) {

System.out.println("No labels found.");

} else {

System.out.println("Labels:");

for (Label label: labels) {

System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());

}
}

// Access Gmail inbox

Gmail.Users.Messages.List request = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("from: " + "helpdesk@b-bets.com");

ListMessagesResponse messagesResponse = request.execute();

request.setPageToken(messagesResponse.getNextPageToken());

// Get ID of the email you are looking for

Gmail.Users.Messages.List request = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("from: " + "support1@24bettle.com");

String messageId = messagesResponse.getMessages().get(0).getId();

Message message = service.users().messages().get(user, messageId).execute();

// Print email body

String emailBody = StringUtils
.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData()));

System.out.println("Email body : " + emailBody);    
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I can get the body for HTML parts of messages which contain tables. Have you noticed this with other email bodies, or just with this one you shared? Also, since you are only getting the first part of the payload (`get(0)`), have you checked other parts? Maybe your desired table is in another part?

Comment: Could you please send me your email address so I can forward you this email? This email is confirmation mail for registration in one online casino, so it's coming from casino BO. As I mentioned only this is the output: email body = null, for other mails (text mails everything is working as expected. Also, since you are only getting the first part of the payload (get(0)), have you checked other parts? Maybe your desired table is in another part? - I will try this tonight, thank you.

Comment: I think that get(0) is related to the order number of emails with a specific id (email address) in the inbox. For example, if I have 10 emails from the email address notification@gmail.com get(0) means that I would like get content from the first one.

Comment: No, in this case get(0) refers to the first part of your message payload. That is, if you try to get the other parts in your payload, you might find the table you're looking for (see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.MessagePart).

Comment: Please check the image (image of email) which I have attached above so you get a better image of what I have to make. I have tried to change get(0) to get(1) but I'm getting only a second email from the same email address from the list.

Comment: I didn't mean the `get(0)` in `String messageId = messagesResponse.getMessages().get(0).getId();`, but the `get(0)` in `message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData())`. If you iterate through all payload parts instead of just retrieving the first one, you should be able to retrieve the table you're looking for.

Comment: Hey Iamblichus, I have tried all numbers up to 8 (0 - 8), but for any of them, I haven't got the expected result. I would like to confirm something with you, you are getting HTML code with the same email and same code? I have tried to add only image or attachment in text email and I'm getting the same: body = null. Only for clear text, I'm getting good results.

Comment: I hadn't tried with that specific email before, but I tried now and I can retrieve the HTML code, it's in the second part of the returned email. Also, while I'm using `Try this API` instead of your exact code, you are accessing the correct fields, so this should work. Can you try accessing this via [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get), and check if you can still not access this?

Comment: I have tried to set get (2) and I got the following message: Exception in thread "main" java. lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 
Yesterday I have tried another email and I can go to the number 8. What I have to enter in this field to try to reproduce this? (I mean it these fields: userId, id, format)

Comment: this is 0-indexed, the second part corresponds to `get(1)`. The third one does not exist.

Comment: Still body = null

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I'm getting the expected data. Are you sure that's the exact email you are retrieving? How was this email sent? Also, have you tried with `Try this API`, as suggested? Do you get the same result?

Comment: This email has been sent from BO of Casino, because of it I wanted to send you the exact email so you can try on a real example (but I don't have your email address for it). Regarding Try this API I'm using for userID: myemailadress ID: <60826bcb.1c69fb81.cb462.608cSMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com> format: Full and I'm getting this error 400

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid id value",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid id value",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidArgument"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Comment: I have tried also different combination: raw/full/minimal > for all of them error message is the same

Comment: You are not providing the correct id. You should find that id via messages.list https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get.

Comment: I got some response using Try this API: https://github.com/StefanTegeltija1992/GmailResponse/blob/main/README.md but I still have body = null in Eclipse

Comment: It's strange for GitHub email (developed also by HTML tables) I'm getting HTML(table) response and for this one for a casino confirmation email, I'm getting null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

The HTML table you are looking for is in a subpart of the message's first part.

#### Explanation:

The response you are getting from `Try this API` has this approximate shape (excluding irrelevant fields):

```
{
  "payload": { 
    "body": { "size": 0 }, 
    "parts": [ 
      { 
        "partId": "0", 
        "body": { "size": 0 }, 
        "parts": [ 
          { 
            "partId": "0.0",
            // Other fields
          }, 
          { 
            "partId": "0.1", 
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "body": { 
              "size": 14024,
              "data": "BASE64_ENCODED_STRING"  // HTML table
            },
            // Other fields
          }
        ] 
      }, 
      { 
        "partId": "1", 
        // Other fields
      } 
    ] 
  }, 
  // Other fields
}
```

If you look at this, it's clear that the content you are looking for is in the first part, but this part itself contains several subparts. The second of these parts contains the desired content.

#### Solution:

You should be able to retrieve the data from this part via:

```
message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getParts().get(1).getBody().getData();
```

Therefore, replace this:

```
String emailBody = StringUtils
.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData()));
```

With this:

```
String emailBody = StringUtils
.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getParts().get(1).getBody().getData()));
```

#### Reference:

- [MessagePart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.MessagePart)

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem. I'm very grateful to you!